# Modularizing GraphQL Types into separate files

Tags: graphql

I have a GraphQL implementation with a single monolithic **types/index.js** file that currently contains two type definitions:

```
const graphql = require('graphql');
const Book = require('../../../models/book');
const Author = require('../../../models/author');

const {
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLSchema,
  GraphQLID,
  GraphQLInt,
  GraphQLList,
  GraphQLNonNull,
} = graphql;

const BookType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Book',
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    name: { type: GraphQLString },
    genre: { type: GraphQLString },
    author: {
      type: AuthorType,
      resolve: (parent, args) => {
        // code to get data from db
        return Author.findById(parent.authorId);
      },
    },
  }),
});

const AuthorType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Author',
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    name: { type: GraphQLString },
    age: { type: GraphQLInt },
    books: {
      type: new GraphQLList(BookType),
      resolve: (parent, args) => {
        // code to get data from db
        return Book.find({authorId: parent.id});
      },
    },
  }),
});

module.exports = {BookType, AuthorType};
```

This is the file I import into my schema.js file where it's used by root queries and mutations:

```
const {
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLSchema,
  GraphQLID,
  GraphQLInt,
  GraphQLList,
  GraphQLNonNull,
} = require('graphql');
const Book = require('../../../models/book');
const Author = require('../../../models/author');
const {BookType, AuthorType} = require('../types');

// QUERIES
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'RootQueryType',
  fields: {
    book: {
      type: BookType,
      args: { id: { type: GraphQLID } },
      resolve: (parent, args) => {
        // code to get data from db
        return Book.findById(args.id);
      },
    },
    author: {
      type: AuthorType,
      args: { id: { type: GraphQLID } },
      resolve: (parent, args) => {
        // code to get data from db
        return Author.findById(args.id);
      },
    },
    books: {
      type: new GraphQLList(BookType),
      resolve: (parent, args) => {
        // code to get data from db
        return Book.find({});
      },
    },
    authors: {
      type: new GraphQLList(AuthorType),
      resolve: (parent, args) => {
        // code to get data from db
        return Author.find({});
      }
    },
  },
});

// MUTATIONS
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const Mutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Mutation',
  fields: {
    addAuthor: {
      type: AuthorType,
      args: {
        name: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
        age: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt) }
      },
      resolve(parent, args) {
        let author = new Author({
          name: args.name,
          age: args.age
        });
        return author.save();
      }
    },
    addBook: {
      type: BookType,
      args: {
        name: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
        genre: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
        authorId: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID) },
      },
      resolve(parent, args) {
        let book = new Book({
          name: args.name,
          genre: args.genre,
          authorId: args.authorId,
        });
        return book.save();
      },
    },
  }
});

module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: RootQuery,
  mutation: Mutation,
});
```

But as the project grows, I am anticipating dozens of types with tons of two-way relationships. So I'd like to modularize all my types into individual files, such as **types/BookType.js**, **types/AuthorType.js**, etc. rather than a single **types/index.js** as I have right now. What's the best way to accomplish this given the two-way relationships?

Answer (score 2):

While segregating the types into separate files, you'll need to handle two-way relationships. In this case, AuthorType needs BookType and vice-versa. So you'll need to import AuthorType in types/BookTypes.js and BookType in types/AuthorType.js but this will introduce a classic **circular dependency** issue (before AuthorType exports it demands BookType and vice-versa) which is common in node projects. You can read more about it [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles). To handle this, shift your require calls at the end of the file in both types. So your code looks somewhat like this:

***types/BookType.js***

```js
const graphql = require('graphql');
const Book = require('../../../models/book');
const Author = require('../../../models/author');

const {
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLSchema,
  GraphQLID,
  GraphQLInt,
  GraphQLList,
  GraphQLNonNull,
} = graphql;

const BookType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Book',
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    name: { type: GraphQLString },
    genre: { type: GraphQLString },
    author: {
      type: AuthorType,
      resolve: (parent, args) => {
        // code to get data from db
        return Author.findById(parent.authorId);
      },
    },
  }),
});

module.exports = BookType;

// This is here to prevent circular dependencies problem which will lead to the formation of infinite loop
const AuthorType = require("./AuthorType");
```

***types/AuthorType.js***

```js
const graphql = require('graphql');
const Book = require('../../../models/book');
const Author = require('../../../models/author');

const {
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLSchema,
  GraphQLID,
  GraphQLInt,
  GraphQLList,
  GraphQLNonNull,
} = graphql;

const AuthorType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Author',
  fields: () => ({
    id: {
      type: GraphQLID
    },
    name: {
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    age: {
      type: GraphQLInt
    },
    books: {
      type: new GraphQLList(BookType),
      resolve: (parent, args) => {
        // code to get data from db
        return Book.find({
          authorId: parent.id
        });
      },
    },
  }),
});

module.exports = AuthorType;

// This is here to prevent circular dependencies problem which will lead to the formation of infinite loop
const BookType = require("./BookType");
```

Also, it is better to have a types/index.js which will act as a handler for import/exports. You export every type to index.js and take whatever you want from it anywhere. This saves you from a lot of messy code because now you can do something like this:

```
const { BookType, AuthorType, OtherType } = require("../types/index");
```